# How to make private method to public method

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm using `twitter` gem and want to get friend_ids more than 75000.
To avoid `Rate Limit` error, I want to handle myself Twitter API more directly.

I redefine `Twitter::Cursor` class like this:

```
class Twitter::Cursor
    def next_cursor
        @attrs[:next_cursor] || -1
    end
    def ids
        @collection
    end
end
```

Only to use private method `next_cursor` I copy and paste original code and define new public method, but I don't think this is a good way to do.

How can I make private method into public method in a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
Twitter::Cursor.send(:public, :next_cursor)
```

I don't know that there really is any "right" way to do this. The original authors probably made that method private for a good reason.